# What to do on death anniversary?

Tags: death

What is the Islamic and proper way to commemorate the death anniversary of a close loved one? I am from Bangladesh and the customs here is something called **Milad**. But I want to know the actual procedure.

Comment: Are you looking at Sunni or Shia view?

Comment: @itsols Sunni would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 6):

In Shias

We do various things(ishal-e-sawab)  for the deceased

- we arrange majis(fazail and masahib of ahel-e-bait)
- we arrange quran khwani sessions(people gather and recite 1 chapter
  of quran each and gift its sawab to the deceased)
- all the familiy members/friends/relative gathered recite one times
  surah hamd and three times surah ikhlas and gift its sawab to the
  deceased
- We give food to the poor with the intention to gift its sawab to the deceased

All these deeds can be done any time of the year, but we try to do it at least once a year.

Comment: Uh-huh @Zia, you named some interesting and actually profitable items. Although they are not to be considered as wajib acts, but they can be counted as mustahab and profitable practices for the dead. God Bless You.